# Масштабирование блока и :hover

Tags: html, css, hover

Добрый день. Предыдущий вопрос был связан с двойными псевдокласами. Относительно разобрался в этом вопросе, но теперь появились другие проблемы. 
При масштабировании заменяемого блока получается каша, текст не выравнивается внутри окна и при наведении курсора на пустое место - блок, который должен заменяться другим блоком попросту исчезает. Всю суть попробую передать в скринах снизу

[image: При наведении курсора на пустой области]

[image: При масштабировании]

```css
    .posle p {
        width: 301px;
        height: 226px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 57.4%;
        left: 50.0%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        opacity: 0;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    
    .wrap .do span {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 75px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 29px 140px;
    }
    


    .posle p:hover,
    img:hover+p {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .posle .col-md-4>div {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    
    .posle {
    display:none;
    }
    .wrap:hover .posle {
        display:block;
    }
    .wrap:hover .do {
        display:none;
    }
```

```html
            <div class="wrap">


               <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="comf">
                  <img src="images/usl7.jpg">
                      <div class="posle"><p>Использование полиграфа при проведении периодических (плановых) проверок помогает выявить нарушения в процессе работы, стимулирует персонал на работу с максимальной самоотдачей.</p></div>
                      <div class="do"><span>Услуги тестирования персонала - 2500 рублей</span></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код прикрепил в первом ответе снизу

Comment: С масштабированием вроде как разобрался, оставлся вопрос с наведением курсора на пустой облости